# How to avoid triggering TableViewer when closing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jface, tableviewer

I'm creating a `TableViewer` which has to respond to selections in other components.

I'm doing some actions in the implemented `selectionChanged` method.

```
@Override
public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
}
```

I want to avoid triggering the operations in `selectionChanged` method when I close the view.

I tried checking the received part:

```
if(part.getSite().getId()!="myviewid")
{
}
```

But I always get the part of the previous selection (in my case `ResourceNavigator`).

How can I check if I selected my view and avoid doing some operations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove your selection listener from the selection service when your view part is disposed

```java
@Override
public void dispose()
{
  ISelectionService service = (ISelectionService)getSite().getService(ISelectionService.class);

  service.removeSelectionListener(myListener);

  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: I am doing that already, using getViewSite().getPage().removeSelectionListener(this);